Setting originalEstimate through Java
I'm trying to set the original Estimate field, but I am always receiving the error message timetracking_originalEstimate cannot be set.
It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.
I couldn't find any information on the correct field id anywhere online
This is my method that is trying to do the update, I already tried multiple parameters for the fieldvalue id like only "originalEstimate"
public void updateEstimate(String issueKey, String estimate) {
        IssueInput input = new IssueInputBuilder().setFieldValue("timetracking_originalEstimate",22).build();
        restClient.getIssueClient().updateIssue(issueKey, input).claim();
}

